# Convert $(element) to vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, refactoring

I am trying to basically flash the element every time some one adds and item to their shopping cart.

below is a snippet from the function

```
 const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('foo-bar')

    for (const element of elements) {
      flashBackground($(element), '#bbbbbb');
    }
```

so I grab the dom elements, then i loop through them and flash their background, which works, but I am trying to refactor out all the old JQuery code to ES6

so when i console log `$(element)` i get back  the below object

```
init [a.foo-bar, context: a.foo-bar]
```

How do i get the equivalent of $(element) in vanilla JS?

Comment: There is no equivalent. `$` returns a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mystery Solved.

I was making a reference to .css on a non jquery object which broke the function
`element.css("background");`

```
function flashBackground(element, color) {
...SOME CODE HERE

//needed to be
getComputedStyle(element)["background"]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the `$()` like this:

```
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('foo-bar');

for (const element of elements) {
  flashBackground(element, '#bbbbbb');
}
```

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a pratical example of the above approach:

```js
const elements = document.getElementsByClassName('foo-bar');

for (const element of elements) {
  alert(element.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<div class="foo-bar">A</div>
<div class="foo-bar">B</div>
<div class="foo-bar">C</div>
<div class="foo-bar">D</div>
```

---

Or you can use the [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method along-with the [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method too like this:

```
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.foo-bar');

elements.forEach(element => flashBackground(element, '#bbbbbb');)
```

Check and run the following **Code Snippet** for a pratical example of the above approach:

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.foo-bar');

elements.forEach(element => alert(element.innerHTML));
```

```html
<div class="foo-bar">A</div>
<div class="foo-bar">B</div>
<div class="foo-bar">C</div>
<div class="foo-bar">D</div>
```

Comment: getElementsByClassName does not return an array or nodeList instead it returns an HTML Collection. If I check the prototype of the HTML Collection, you can see there is no array methods, but instead `Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()` 

but that aside, dropping the $() didnt help, tried that before posting :(

Comment: @DenisSDujota But regardless, either approach should work as seen in the demo snippets I have added to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery's *$(query)* selector is effectively an abstraction of [Document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector).  Like the jQuery implemention, querySelector() can be used to target nodes via any standard CSS selector.